# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: authtoken_token.user_id

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I'm new in Django rest framework and I'm trying do a unit test using Token for my API, but it kept throwing `IntegrityError`. I've researched many blogs to find the solution but couldn't find. Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code that I've tried

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIRequestFactory, force_authenticate
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

from myapp.api.views import UserViewSet


class UserTestCase(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.superuser = User.objects.create_user(username='superuser', email='uid.sawyer@gmail.com',
                                                  password='superuser',
                                                  is_staff=True)
        self.factory = APIRequestFactory()

        self.token = Token.objects.create(user=self.superuser)
        self.token.save()

    def test_list(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/api/users/')
        force_authenticate(request, user=self.superuser, token=self.token)
        response = UserViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: You seem to insert the same `user` multiple times with your `Token.objects.create(..)`

Comment: on which line exactly is this error happening? if you don't know, please show the entire error trace.

Comment: Its when creating token ```Token.objects.create(user=self.superuser)```, I gave a try by removing ```self.token.save()``` and I've also tried to put the token creation code in ```setUpClass()``` classmethod but it's still throwing the IntegrityError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I got it. I didn't notice that I had created Token in signals wherein each User creation Token was created. Thanks @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 3):

unique constraint failed: authtoken_token.user_id
This error is coming because token already exists for this user in database. So when it tries to create new token with same user_id it gives an error

If you look at the admin token already exists for users

This is referenced from `https://excellencetechnologies.in/blog/django-rest-api-authentication-part5/`:

Do a try-except function:

```py
class UserAuth(APIView):

   # Manager User Login and other things
    

    def post(self, request):
        
        # login
       
        user = authenticate(
            username=request.data.get("username"),
            password=request.data.get("password")
            )
        if user is not None:
            # A backend authenticated the credentials

            try:
                token = Token.objects.get(user_id=user.id)

            except Token.DoesNotExist:
                token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

            return Response(token.key)

        else:
            # No backend authenticated the credentials
            return Response([], status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Junaid Girkar, I suppose little update of code section would help to make it more readable ;)

Comment: @Nozim Have made some edits to improve the readability of the code. Feel free to mention any other ways I can improve. Am new to Stackoverflow and am always willing to correct my mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to the community! Thanks for the modifications. It's looks much better now.